# Simple Injector with Generic interfaces and composition - Not registering interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, composition, simple-injector

I am moving from inheritance to compositon, as you can see from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653153/composition-migrating-from-inheritance

Now i have got it all working, but simple injector wants me to manually register each interface with each type being passed in.  Here is the striped down code.

I have IBaseEntityService, which BaseEntityService implements, like so

```
public interface IEntityBaseService<T> where T : class, IEntityBase
{
    IDataContext Context { get; }

    Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsync();

    Task<T> GetAsync(long id);
}

public class EntityBaseService<T> : IEntityBaseService<T>
    where T : class, IEntityBase
{
    protected IDataContext _context;

    public IDataContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            return _context;
        }
    }

    public EntityBaseService(IDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<T> GetAsync(long id)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Where(e => e.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

Now i have a IValidationService and ValidationService implements that, like so

```
public interface IValidationService<T> 
    where T : class, IEntityBase
{
    Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(T entity);

    Task<int> AddAsync(T entity);

    Task<int> UpdateAsync(T entity);
}

public class ValidationService<T> : IValidationService<T>
    where T : class, IEntityBase
{
    private IEntityBaseService<T> _service;
    private IValidator<T> _validator = null;

    public IDataContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            return _service.Context;
        }
    }

    public ValidationService(IEntityBaseService<T> service, IValidator<T> validator)
    {
        _service = service;
        _validator = validator;
    }

    public Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(T entity)
    {
        if (_validator == null) throw new MissingFieldException("Validator does not exist for class " + entity.GetType().ToString() + ". override method if no validation needed");
        return _validator.ValidateAsync(entity);
    }

    public async Task<int> AddAsync(T entity)
    {
        var results = await ValidateAsync(entity);

        if (!results.IsValid)
        {
            throw new ValidationException(results.Errors);
        }

        return await _service.AddAsync(entity);
    }

    public async Task<int> UpdateAsync(T entity)
    {
        var results = await ValidateAsync(entity);

        if (!results.IsValid)
        {
            throw new ValidationException(results.Errors);
        }

        return await _service.UpdateAsync(entity);
    }
}
```

Now i can use services, and pass in each interface.  So i have a IContentService and ContentService which implements that.  This service uses both IEntityBaseService and IValidationService

```
public interface IContentService
{
    Task<Content> GetAsync(long id);

    Task<int> AddAsync(Content entity);

    Task<int> UpdateAsync(Content entity);
}

public class ContentService : IContentService
{
    private IEntityBaseService<Content> _service;
    private IValidationService<Content> _validation;

    public ContentService(IEntityBaseService<Content> service, IValidationService<Content> validation)
    {
        _service = service;
        _validation = validation;
    }

    public async Task<Content> GetAsync(long id)
    {
        var content = await _service.Context.Contents
            .Where(e => e.Id == id)
            .WhereNotDeleted()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (content != null)
        {
            content.Attachments = await _service.Context.Attachments
                .Where(e => e.ContentId == id)
                .WhereNotDeleted()
                .ToListAsync();
        }

        return content;
    }

    public Task<int> AddAsync(Content entity)
    {
        return _validation.AddAsync(entity);
    }

    public Task<int> UpdateAsync(Content entity)
    {
        return _validation.UpdateAsync(entity);
    }
}
```

Now in my config file, i have this, which works, but if i have another service, and i have about 20 of them, i do not want to type this out for each one.

```
container.Register<IEntityBaseService<Content>, EntityBaseService<Content>>();
container.Register<IValidationService<Content>, ValidationService<Content>>();
container.Register<IValidator<Content>, ContentValidator>();

container.Register<IContentService, ContentService>();
```

So i looked online and i think i can use the RegisterManyForOpenGeneric method instead of registering IEntityBaseService and IValidatioNService, but i cannot get it too work. I have wrote

```
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IEntityBaseService<>), typeof(IEntityBaseService<>).Assembly);
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IValidationService<>), typeof(IValidationService<>).Assembly);
```

And i get an error saying

> The constructor of type ContentService contains the parameter of type
>   IEntityBaseService with name 'service' that is not
>   registered. Please ensure IEntityBaseService is registered in
>   the container, or change the constructor of ContentService.

Maybe i have set up my entities incorrectly, so just encase, here are the basic entities for this example

```
public interface IEntityBase
{
    long Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class EntityBase : IEntityBase
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class Content : EntityBase, IAudit
{
    public short Position { get; set; }

    public Content() 
    {
        Position = 1;
    }

}
```

Any help much appreciated on both simple injector and the code in general

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong registration method.

`RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` exists to support the following scenario:-

```
container.Register<IValidate<Customer>, CustomerValidator>();
container.Register<IValidate<Employee>, EmployeeValidator>();
container.Register<IValidate<Order>, OrderValidator>();
container.Register<IValidate<Product>, ProductValidator>();

// can replace the above with the following:-
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
  typeof(IValidate<>),
  typeof(IValidate<>).Assembly);
```

> By default RegisterManyForOpenGeneric searches the supplied assembly for all types that implement the [specified open generic] interface and registers each type by their ***specific (closed generic)*** interface. *[Emphasis mine]*

Note how the concrete types aren't themselves generic (i.e. `CustomerValidator` implements the closed generic interface `IValidate<Customer>`). This works fine for your `ContentValidator` but is no good for open generic classes implementing open generic interfaces like your `EntityBaseService<Content>` and `ValidationService<Content>`.

You're looking for:-

```
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
  typeof(IEntityBaseService<>),
  typeof(EntityBaseService<>));
```

Answer (score 0):

`RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` has been marked obsolete now.

```
container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), new[] { typeof(IValidator<>).Assembly });
```

Is the way to go now.

http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html