# Auto-registration of generic classes

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I'm trying to inject a generic class with Simple Injector.
However, it fails with

> SimpleInjector.ActivationException: No registration for type ... could be found

Here's the code to reproduce it:

```cs
using System;

namespace ErrorReproduction
{
    public class GenericClass<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IGenericInterface<T>
    {
        void DoSomething(T value);
    }

    public class NonGenericService : IGenericInterface<string>
    {
        public void DoSomething(string value) =>
            Console.WriteLine($"NonGeneric DoSomething (string): {value}");
    }

    public class GenericService<T> : IGenericInterface<GenericClass<T>>
    {
        public virtual void DoSomething(GenericClass<T> v) =>
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"Generic DoSomething {v.Value.GetType().Name}: {v.Value}");
    }

    /*
    public class StringService : GenericService<string>
    {
    }
    */

    public static class Test
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();
            container.RegisterSingleton(
                typeof(IGenericInterface<>),
                typeof(IGenericInterface<>).Assembly);

            // works
            container.GetInstance<IGenericInterface<string>>()
                .DoSomething("non-generic-test");

            // breaks without StringService (No registration for type
            // IGenericInterface<GenericClass<string>>)
            container.GetInstance<IGenericInterface<GenericClass<string>>>()
                .DoSomething(
                    new GenericClass<string> {Value = "di-generic-test"});
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment-in the StringService above, it works. However, without it I receive the following exception:

> Unhandled exception. SimpleInjector.ActivationException: No registration for type IGenericInterface<GenericClass<string>> could be found. at ErrorReproduction.Test.Main(String[] args) in ErrorReproduction/Test.cs:line 45

If I create a specific implementation that itself is not generic anymore, DI works.
However, even without the specific one, the `GenericService<T>`, which is not abstract, is enough and should be injectable.

I'd like to not have to create a specific class for each case of `GenericService<T>` that we will have. They would just be empty like the above `StringService`, fully relying on the implementation of the generic service.

Is there a way to get the DI working for a case like this?

Edit:
Turned out my use case is not exactly what I described above. However, the comments and answer provided got me on the right track.
In the end, this is what worked for me:

```
container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IMapper<,>), typeof(IMapper<,>).Assembly);
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IMapper<,>),
    typeof(SimpleTimedValueProxyMapper<>),
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    ctx => !ctx.Handled);
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IMapper<,>),
    typeof(TimedValueProxyMapper<,>),
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    ctx => !ctx.Handled);
```

Which, given the classes in the first example, would probably resolve to this (have not tested it):

```
container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IGenericInterface<>), typeof(IGenericInterface<>).Assembly);
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IGenericInterface<>),
    typeof(GenericService<>),
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    ctx => !ctx.Handled);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple Injector with Generic interfaces and composition - Not registering interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678417/simple-injector-with-generic-interfaces-and-composition-not-registering-interf)

Comment: @Renat: That's a really old question. The API has changed too much for its answer to be applicable to this question, unfortunately. I don't consider this question a duplicate of that specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML documentation of `RegisterXXX(Type, Assembly[])` states the following (emphasis mine):

> Registers all concrete, ***non-generic,*** public and internal types in the given set
> of assemblies

In other words, by default, only non-generic types are registered; your `GenericService<T>` is skipped in this auto-registration process.

This is by design, and done so because generic types often need special handling. That's because they can easily overlap and their order of registration might be important.

So to fix this, you can do the following:

```
container.RegisterSingleton(
    typeof(IGenericInterface<>),
    typeof(IGenericInterface<>).Assembly);

container.RegisterSingleton(
    typeof(IGenericInterface<>), typeof(GenericService<>));
```

When there are many generic types, and they don't overlap with one another, you can instruct Simple Injector to also include generic type definitions in the registration. This can be done as follows:

```cs
container.Register(
    typeof(IGenericInterface<>),
    container.GetTypesToRegister(
        typeof(IGenericInterface<>),
        new[] { typeof(IGenericInterface<>).Assembly },
        new TypesToRegisterOptions { IncludeGenericTypeDefinitions = true }));
```

Comment: Thank you! While this isn't exactly what I needed, it did bring me on the right path.
In the end, this worked for me:

cc.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IMapper<,>), typeof(IMapper<,>).Assembly);

cc.RegisterConditional(typeof(IMapper<,>), typeof(SimpleTimedValueProxyMapper<>), Lifestyle.Singleton, ctx => !ctx.Handled);

cc.RegisterConditional(typeof(IMapper<,>), typeof(TimedValueProxyMapper<,>), Lifestyle.Singleton, ctx => !ctx.Handled);